# Redash chart converts x-axis to years when it's not

Tags: redash

I ran a query that has results similar to these:

```
_col0 | _col1
1     | 151
2     | 4324
...   
17    | 23413
```

When I try to create a chart, putting `_col0` on the x-axis presto assumes the axis indicates years and gives me a graph with 20XX instead of XX when XX is a two digit number.

I would just go with it, except when `_col0` is < 10 the year it's translated to is 1970 for some reason, which really messes up my chart.

How can I fix this?

[image: an example chart]
the data for the x-axis is integers 1..30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the X Axis type to `Category` or `Linear`:

[image: X Axis Settings]